# Loading XML into Flex AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, loader

I am trying to be able to load all XML data from an XML document and have been failing all night on it even with research

Here is a snippet of the XML I am trying to load:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <id>urn:uuid:5762c9e8-4e65-3b0c-83b3-7874683f3dbe</id>
  <link href="/v1/espi_third_party_batch_feed" rel="self">
  </link>
  <title type="text">Opower ESPI Third Party Batch Feed v1</title>
  <updated>2012-04-03T22:55:36.364Z</updated>

  <entry>
    <id>urn:uuid:baa6a50a-1306-3680-80a4-51d228db8f25</id>
    <link href="/v1/User/3560606/UsagePoint/6403112/MeterReading/1/IntervalBlock/1" rel="self">
    </link>
    <content type="xml">
      <IntervalBlock xmlns="http://naesb.org/espi">
        <interval>
          <duration>3600</duration>
          <start>1299128400</start>
        </interval>
        <IntervalReading>
          <timePeriod>
            <duration>3600</duration>
            <start>1299128400</start>
          </timePeriod>
          <value>436</value>
        </IntervalReading>
      </IntervalBlock>
    </content>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Here is a snippet of the AS3 code I am puzzled on in the XmlLoader:

```
    public function returnArray():Array
    {           
        var ATOM:Namespace = new Namespace("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
        var NAESB:Namespace = new Namespace("http://naesb.org/espi");
        trace("entered returnArray");
        var tempArray:Array = new Array();
        var x:Number = 0;
        var y:Number = 0;
        var entries = this.docXML.ATOM::entry;
        trace(entries.length());                //returns 4 and supposed to
        trace(entries[3].content.length());     //returns 0 supposed to return 1
        trace(this.docXML.ATOM::entry[3].content.NAESB::interval.length()); //returns 0`enter code here`
```

Comment: I'm sorry that you're failing at this task.  Can you tell us why/how you're failing?  What is the problem?  Do you get a runtime error?  Or something else?  Did I miss the part where you shared the code that loads the XML?

Comment: No errors its just not allowing me to gain access to the nested xmlns in the tag IntervalBlock so that I can read the time/energy usage nested inside of that tag and since I am trying to make this for an application that any1 can use I cant just remove the xmlns tags as this data is provided in a standard format by energy companies across the US

Comment: Your subject line claims the issue is loading the data; but it sounds like your issue is accessing the data after it is loaded.  Is that correct?  You say "its not allowing you to gain access to nested xmlns?  What isn't?  Your XML Does not have any special namespaced items; but it looks like you're trying to access them as if they were in a namespace.

Comment: It is allowing me to view it that is it; if i do a trace(this.docXML.ATOM::entry); if will parse everything out but cannot access anything tags beyond event even though flex is willing to view it allafer that in the XML

Answer (score 0):

First, you should take a look at [the documentation for e4x](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=13_Working_with_XML_01.html). Secondly: what are you exactly trying to do?

The last line you could change to `this.docXML.ATOM::entry.content..NAESB::interval.length()` but I'm not sure what you're really trying to get out of the xml document.  Getting the length of a node is not very useful for getting actual data out of an xml file.

Comment: I am trying to actually gain access to the data inside of the entry tag; using the namespace class I was able to access the entry class but cant seem to get the namespace class to give me access to anything inside of the entry class... But if i were to trace(entries[3]); it reads the whole xml doc.  My issue is that since this data is information provided by an electrical company I can't alter their data if I want others to use my application so I am trying to access interval tag to use the data in there but since its nested inside of another xmlns i cant seem to gain access

Comment: I have a feeling it has to deal with the id urn:uuid which makes it unique

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this thanks frankhermes and www.Flextras.com for aiding my learning is in order to continue to traverse there is the need to add another namespace of ATOM into the xml to keep traversing

```
var entries = this.docXML.ATOM::entry;
trace(entries[3].content.length());
```

should be

```
var entries = this.docXML.ATOM::entry;
trace(entries[3].ATOM::content.length());
```